# Injection does not work when GetBuilder is in parent class

Tags: flutter-getx

I have a parent class where I define the generic behaviour of a widget type. Each child class implements a method where it returns its controller (GetxController) and another one where it returns the particular widget of each of them.

The bug occurs when I navigate from A to B doing a Get.offAndToNamed(B) because the controller of B is not injected and therefore, when executing a Get.Find<controller_B> the exception is thrown.

In fact, debugging, I have seen that the A controller ends up having 2 updaters. How can it be possible?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      initialRoute: Routes.start,
      routes: getRoutes(context),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}

abstract class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @protected
  Widget myBuild();

  @protected
  GetxController myController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder(
      init: myController(),
      builder: (controller) {
        debugPrint(controller.toString());
        return myBuild();
      },
    );
  }
}

class A extends MyStatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget myBuild() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(color: Colors.red),
        ),
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Get.offAndToNamed(Routes.b);
            },
            child: const Text('Púlsame'))
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  GetxController myController() {
    return MyController();
  }
}

class B extends MyStatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget myBuild() {
    var ctrl = Get.find<MyController2>();
    return Container(color: Colors.blue);
  }

  @override
  GetxController myController() {
    return MyController2();
  }
}

class MyController extends GetxController {}

class MyController2 extends GetxController {}

class Routes {
  static const String start = '/';
  static const String b = '/b';
}

Map<String, Widget Function(BuildContext)> getRoutes(BuildContext context) {
  return {
    Routes.start: (context) => A(),
    Routes.b: (context) => B(),
  };
}
```